# Batch redirect URLs using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have been trying to do a batch redirect from hee old URL to the new one. However I think I might be doing something wrong. The redirect works but partially.

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/blog/.*$ https://elashsupplies.com.au/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^blogs/blog/tagged/.*$ https://elashsupplies.com.au/blog/tag/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This redirects the URL but only to /blog not to the post it self. Was wondering what I might be doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: You are not capturing `.*` in `$1` using `(...)` in patterns

Comment: e.g. use: `RewriteRule ^blogs/blog/(.*)$ https://elashsupplies.com.au/blog/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did try that but that still redirects me to /blog only.

https://elashsupplies.com.au/blogs/blog/54146113-which-tweezers-are-best-for-lashing should go to https://elashsupplies.com.au/blog/54146113-which-tweezers-are-best-for-lashing

Comment: Sorry, it was cached. It does work :) thank you heaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating my comment to an answer.

Problem is that you're not capturing text from regex pattern in your rules even though you're using back-reference `$1` in target. You should be using:

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/blog/(.*)$ https://elashsupplies.com.au/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NE,NC]

RewriteRule ^blogs/blog/tagged/(.*)$ https://elashsupplies.com.au/blog/tag/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Also important is to keep these redirect rules **before** all other rewrite rules in your .htaccess. Consider moving these rules to Apache or virtual host config file for better performance.